# A series of tests IS / ARE performed

Tags: singular-subject-and-verb

How to correctly write "A series of tests IS performed" or "A series of tests ARE performed".

My thinking is that the verb "performed" is related to the noun "a series", which is singular, because it has "a" in front of it. However If I google (for instance [here](https://ludwig.guru/) ) I see that both scenarios are used.

Comment: Why not use the active instead of the passive? English doesn't have number agreement for objects. _We performed a series of tests_.

Comment: I think that with 'series', notional agreement is available. Are you highlighting the single series or the multiple tests? "A series of tests IS performed" shows formal agreement or notional agreement with focus on the single series, while "A series of tests ARE performed" uses notional agreement focusing on the multiple tests, and treating 'a series of' almost as a quantifier ("A lot of tests ARE performed").